# Homework question: How deep is the shallow and deep end of a swimming pool?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

I am not sure if my answer is right. The graph shows how the depth of water in a swimming pool increases when water is pumped in at a constant rate.

Question: Assuming the pool was full after 50 minutes, how deep was the shallow end? How about the deep end?

My answer is 1 meter for the shallow end and 2.5 meters for the deep end. But I am not sure if my answer is correct.

Here's the graph:

[image]

The y-axis is depth in meters and the x-axis is time in minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is incorrect. The deep end is $2.5 \ \text m$ deep and the shallow end is $1.5 \ \text m$ deep.

Comment: How is the 1.5 m the depth of the shallow end?

Comment: The tank fills from the bottom up so the shallow end is $1 \ \text m$ above the deep end.

Comment: I still don't get it. Does this have something to do with the gradients of each piece of the graph?

Comment: Not really. The gradients change when the depth is $1 \ \text m$. But this is $1 \ \text m$ from the bottom of the tank, which is $2.5 \ \text m$ deep. So, the shallow end is $2.5-1=1.5 \ \text m$ deep.

Comment: I think I got it. I imagined the pool 2.5 m deep. There is like 1 m step (like on a ladder) before you reach the shallow end. So the shallow end must be 1.5 meters deep.

Comment: @harpey1111 Yes, that is correct.